# No sound for Dell 1525 laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 (only HDMI option in Sound settings)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, dell, soundcard

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop and I get no sound from it. In *Sound* settings I have only an HDMI option. Here is the output of `play -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 7: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
[2]+  Done                    paprefs
```

Also this is:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Conexant Generic
Codec: Silicon Image Generic
Codec: SigmaTel Generic
```

Ι also used this command with no result:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

I tried removing/reinstalling the ALSA packages. After that, my headphones are working, only the speakers of the laptop do not work.

Please help me, as this is the 4th time I try to install Ubuntu with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your speakers may be detected as unplugged which causes them to be ignored.

**Temporary fix:**

1. Install `pavucontrol`:

   ```
   sudo apt install pavucontrol
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   pavucontrol
   ```
3. *Configuration* tab → *Profile* → *Analogue Stereo Output (unplugged) (unavailable)*

With the above, the speakers should work, but it will reset when headphones are unplugged or system rebooted.

**Permanent fix:**

1. Install `alsa-tools-gui`:

   ```
   sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   hdajackretask
   ```
3. Parser hints → `jack_detect = no`
4. Apply now.
5. Install boot override.

Comment: Thank you very much,  this orders  1)  pavucontrol  2)Configuration tab > Profile > Analogue Stereo Duplex (unavailable).           successfully   the speakers start work only i have to do every time after repoot                                                                           ,  but The Permanent fix does not work