# Sound card no longer recognized after upgrading from 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 20.10

Dell Precision 5750, on 20.04 the sound was working just fine.

But then, when I upgraded to 20.10, the system stopped recognizing my sound card, and a further upgrade to 21.04 didn't change anything. Force reloading/reinstalling alsa didn't help.

Sound settings say "Dummy output" as an output device.

Alsamixer only sees HDA Nvidia as a sound card for HDMI. So does "aplay -l":

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

"lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio":

```
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [1028:0990]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1ada] (rev a1)
```

"dmesg | grep -i audio":

```
    [    0.171470] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
    [    4.994502] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
    [    5.018582] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
    [    5.018614] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    5.018803] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
    [    5.018860] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
    [    5.023774] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
    [    5.038285] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
    [    5.157409] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:5:1-88707
    [    5.157413] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:16:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
    [   64.498859] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
    [   64.499051] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
    [   64.499130] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
    [   64.505167] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
    [   64.516834] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 4
    [   64.660436] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 1:5:1-88707
    [   64.660440] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:16:0 Kernel ABI 3:18:0
```

"lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel":

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         147456  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               118784  14 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_soc_rt715,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_rt711,snd_soc_rt1308_sdw,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

So I surmise that my card is an onboard Intel Realtek something, and that it should use the snd_hda_intel driver. I've also double-checked that it was switched on in BIOS.

Any ideas where to look next?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Also post the output of

```
$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
```

in the question

Comment: Thank you and please see below, the output was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Already tried installing linux-modules-extra, says it's already the newest version.

I also tried looking at dependencies as well, but can't really tell which are installed and which aren't by this output:

```
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/ac97_bus.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/soc/snd-soc-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-bus.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-cadence.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-generic-allocation.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/soundwire/soundwire-intel.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-17-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko probe_mask=1
```

Comment: I suggest you:
1) Post all additional info by editing the question, not as an answer.
2) Post the output of all commands in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul
3) Use appropriate markdown formating.
All this increases your chances of solving the problem. The time invested will surely pay off.

Comment: In the meantime, you ma check these links
1) https://forum.zorin.com/t/dell-precision-5750-no-sound-dummy-output/3109
2) https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/hj8oxw/xps_17_9700_no_audio_on_linux_also_hardware_is/
3) https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/hl5z86/xps_17_9700_working_audio_on_linux_details_in/
4) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234958/no-sound-ubuntu-20-for-dell-i-have-in-settinghdmi-only
5) https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/202002-27725